# CakePHP development server

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.7

I am new to CakePHP, I have installed it using composer with following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app new_cake_app
```

When I browse http://localhost/new_cake_app/ the default page is loaded

But when I run the development server using bin\cake server for windows and browse the URL: http://localhost:8765/, It seems to be loading with no result

[image]

I am using PHP 7.3.3 and have enabled extensions intl, mbstring as well as mod_rewrite in on

Comment: Are you trying to access `http://localhost:8765/` from your pc or remote from the server ?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa: I am accessing it from my PC

Comment: In that case you should access it by `IP` or `name`. `localhost` refers to your local machine.

Comment: I am accessing it from my machine only, so I guess localhost should work

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding exception to anti virus